# jQuery Validation Boolean Help

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm doing a workaround to a complex problem and it requires me to do it the way I am doing it.

I'm testing for the presence of a certain class - `intra-field-label`. The elements *will* have multiple classes. How can I do this?

```
...
arn: {
    required: function(element) {
        return //element #arn has no class 'intra-field-label' means TRUE
    }
},
ann: {
    required: function(element) {
        return //element #ann has no class 'intra-field-label' means TRUE
    }
},
...
```

The fields both have the name and id "arn" and "ann", respectively.

**Update:**

I found that the text input has a class called "intra-field-label" when there is the label present (indicating that the user has not input anything). Perhaps I can test for the presence? I don't believe .val() will work here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change them to `return ($("#arn").val() != "Enter the Retailer Name");` and `return ($("#ann").val() != "Enter Your Name");` for it to treat them like proper conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test whether the element has the `intra-field-label` class or not:

```
return $(element).hasClass('intra-field-label');
```